# .NET MySql batch Stored Procedure with Output Parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute a batch call to a stored procedure to sync data between two systems. My SP has several in parameters and 1 out parameter. Everything works fine except I can't seem to get the out parameter.

I created a simplified sample that outlines my issue.

My Stored Procedure looks like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sampleProc`(IN i_val INT, OUT o_val INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT i_val + i_val INTO o_val;
END
```

My .NET code

```
class TestingSP
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("i_val", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("o_val", typeof(System.Int32)));

        for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["i_val"] = x;
            dr["o_val"] = 0;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();

        command.CommandText = "sampleProc";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;

        command.Parameters.Add("?i_val", MySqlDbType.Int32).SourceColumn = "i_val";

        MySqlParameter output = new MySqlParameter();
        output.ParameterName = "?o_val";
        output.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
        output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        output.SourceColumn = "o_val";

        command.Parameters.Add(output);

        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        conBuilder.Server = "myserver";
        conBuilder.UserID = "root";
        conBuilder.Password = "password";
        conBuilder.Port = 3308;
        conBuilder.Database = "test_db";

        Console.WriteLine("Rows: " + dt.Rows.Count);

        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conBuilder.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;

            using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter())
            {
                da.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
                da.ContinueUpdateOnError = true;
                da.UpdateCommand = command;
                da.UpdateBatchSize = 50;
                da.Update(dt);


                foreach(var c  in dt.GetErrors())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Err: " + c.RowError);
                }


                foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", row["i_val"], row["o_val"]);
                }
            }
        }

        command.Dispose();

        Console.WriteLine("Done...");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I've been scratching my head for a couple of days trying to get this to work but no matter what I try o_val is always zero.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is probably not the reason...but this doesnt look right - output.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.String

Comment: Your right, i fixed that in sample code, I had just copied it from my other code.

Comment: I don't see that you even try to get the value. You access it after the command is executed with: `command.Parameters["?o_val"].Value` but you are executing once for each row in the DataTable so I don't know what you expect to do with it.

Comment: do you need the question marks? in the parameter names...i looked at examples and didnt see that

Comment: Maybe you can better explain what exactly you need. This is clearly prototyping code so there is something you are trying to figure out. You will not be able to get the output parameter values from a data adapter update.

Comment: Crowcoder, I am writing a program that syncs data to a database. It usually around 8K to 9K rows so thats why I am using the batch method. I was hoping to use the output parameter so i would  know whether the row was ignored, created, or  updated. Its not mission critical functionality just for logging purposes. However the challenge of getting it to work has got the best of me

Comment: So I guess the general issue is that calling update, won't update the actual datatable rows like I was hoping.

Comment: It will update the rows, that has nothing to do with an OUTPUT parameter. A data adapter performs inserts, updates and deletes based on the RowState. If you want to do full CRUD you need to provide an insert command, an update command and a delete command if you want to delete. [Read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters), it tells you how to handle row errors.

Comment: Does the stored proc work when you just call it from MySql Workbench or whatever? Try ```SET @o_val = i_val + i_val ;```

Comment: pmcilreavy - Yeah it works fine in Workbench. Its purely my implementation in .NET.

Comment: Its not full CRUD, in my stored procedure the command is an INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. What I meant was by setting the direction on the parameter to output i was hoping it would update the value in the datatable but looking at it some more that it looks like it wasn't designed to work that way